# Unbiasedness of Sample Variance (missing a step in the proof)

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Again, I don't see the step between the formula for $S^2$ (first equality) and the second equality. In particular, how is he changing it from $(X_i - \bar X)^2$ to $(X_i^2 - n\bar X^2)$?

Also, $V(\bar X) = \sigma^2 / n$?

Everything else makes sense.

(NOTE: Thank you, I'm finally starting to grasp these concepts and it's great!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $i$,
$$
(X_i-\bar X)^2=X_i^2-2X_i\bar X+\bar X^2,
$$
hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)-2\bar X\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)+n\bar X^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)-2\bar X\cdot(n\bar X)+n\bar X^2,
$$
and finally,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)-n\bar X^2.
$$

Comment: I love how you make it so easy for me to understand. After I see this, I'm like, "duh, of course!" Thank you!

Comment: Also, I believe I figured out the second part of my question! $V(\bar X) = V\left(1/n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) = 1/n^2 V\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right) = 1/n^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^nV(X_i)\right) = n/n^2 V(X_i) = \sigma^2 / n$ Wooohooo! (Feel like a big deal for using TeX :) )

Comment: This is quite correct.